# Google calendar sharing

Tags: google-calendar

I am a Google Apps administrator in the process of transferring a multitude of secondary calendars from a previous Google account. So following advice from [Easiest way to transfer Google data between accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26245/easiest-way-to-transfer-google-data-between-accounts) I did the following:

**Old Account**

- Download calendar and save as ICS

**New Administor Account**

- Create new calendar
- Select "Share Calendar With Others", "Share calendar with everyone in the organization - see all event details"

However nobody in the organization can see the new calendar under "Other Calendars" nor do they get any form of notification.

It seems everyone in the organization has to now somehow add this calendar(s) via "Add a colleague's calendar" OR I have to add each user's **new** Google account. This is turning into an administrative nightmare.

The behavior I want is:

- Maintain a list of calendars that everyone in the organization has access to
- By default all users in organization have "See All Event Details" access. Certain organization users have "Make Changes To Events" and Apps Administrators have "Make Changes AND Sharing"
- As users are added/removed to the Google Apps domain the access to these calendars are **automatically** granted/revoked ie. Organization users should not have to do anything to get access to the list of calendars.

I am sure there is a simple solution to this that I am missing, so if someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else wanting to get a list of calendars, this Google Script might help:

```
function listCalendarsToLogger(){
  var calList = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();

  for(var i=0; i<calList.length; i++){
    var cal = calList[i];
    Logger.log(cal.getName())
  }
}
```

That will list all the calendars you have access to. I'm not sure what it would do for an App admin, whether it would show all user's calendars too.

Comment: Hi, What Script is this. Where in my application can I add this code?

Comment: There's a [guide to using Google Script on calendars here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/apps-script). But I'll warn you now I've tried this script and it doesn't appear to do anything.